# checking if a string that is a array of JSONObject is empty

Tags: java, json-simple

So I am receiving, a jsonobject from an api call.

inside the jsonobject there is a field that can hold an array of JSONObjects

for example

{ "order":[]}

how can I check if the array is empty or not?

JSONSimple library

```
JSONObject[] check = new JSONObject[0];

JSONObject g = new JSONObject();
g.put("test", check);

System.out.println(((List<JSONObject>)g.get("test")).size());
```

Actual result: error

Desired result: size of json[]

Thanks

Comment: First, name is `"order"`, not `"test"`. Second, an array is a `JSONArray`, not a `List`.

Comment: `org.json.simple.JSONArray` implements `List<Object>`. See [here](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/blob/master/src/main/java/org/json/simple/JSONArray.java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cast an array of JsonObject (JSONObject[]) to a List of JSONObject (List) - they are 2 different class with 2 different heirarchy. Cast it to JSONObject[], and since now it is an array and not a list, use length, not size().

```
    JSONObject[] check = new JSONObject[0];

    JSONObject g = new JSONObject();
    g.put("test", check);

    //System.out.println(((List<JSONObject>) g.get("test")).size());
    System.out.println(((JSONObject[]) g.get("test")).length);
```